# i was trying to make a tradingindicator however i am facing issues

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am given the error: 20:03:23 — Compilation error. Line 15: Mismatched input ',' expecting ')'
but after countless research and asking ai for help i cannot continue

my code is:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © sagadsagode

//@version=5

// Ichimoku Breakout strategy

// Input parameters
conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")

// Calculate Ichimoku Cloud
donchian(len) => (highest(len), lowest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)[0]
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)[0]
leadLine1 = (conversionLine + baseLine) / 2
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)[0]

// Plot Ichimoku Cloud
plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")
p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7, title="Leading Span A")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A, title="Leading Span B")
plot(leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Upper Line", display = display.none)
plot(leadLine1 < leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Lower Line", display = display.none)
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))

// Identify trend
trendUp = close > leadLine1
trendDown = close < leadLine1

// Identify breakouts
breakoutUp = ta.crossover(close, leadLine1)
breakoutDown = ta.crossunder(close, leadLine1)

// Buy/sell signals
buySignal = trendUp and breakoutUp
sellSignal = trendDown and breakoutDown

// Plot signals
plot(buySignal ? close : na, color=color.green, linewidth=5, title="Buy Signal")
plot(sellSignal ? close : na, color=color.red, linewidth=5, title="Sell Signal")
```

but it says there is an issue with line 15

Comment: Your function  donchian(len) => (highest(len), lowest(len)) doesn't have any meaning, what do ou want to calculate with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donchian is calculated as below:

```
math.avg(ta.highest(len), ta.lowest(len))
```

Your function is missing the `math.avg()` part.

So, it should be:

```
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.highest(len), ta.lowest(len))
```

Also, your `input` functions should be `input.int()` since you are using arguments like `minval`.